django: unable to customise the admin history page
I want to display the old and new values in the history log page.
I have been able to save the data and print it to the server but I cannot seem to customise the history page layout / rendering... it simply ignores my file.
I have created a custom html file in the folder:
project/app/templates/admin/app/modelname/history.html
(project/api/templates/admin/api/apicustomer/history.html)
after several hours of GPT i give up! Can andybody advise?
